# how to get bash/windows to recognize c/libraries

Tags: c

windows 10 home, version 20H2, build 19042.1110

I am trying to follow along a C tutorial on linkedin Learning, the course told me to install codeblocks, so I did. I also have visual studio, vs code, bash, and ubuntu running from virtual box.

so anyways the tutorial has me create hello world in vim using c code, then it tells me to use clang, so I went and installed LLVM and restarted my computer so bash would recognize clang. ran the command clang 01_01-hello.c in bash and got this error.

```
$ clang 01_01-hello.c
clang: warning: unable to find a Visual Studio installation; try running Clang from a developer command prompt [-Wmsvc-not-found]
01_01-hello.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

and I don't understand what it is I need to do here. I tried using ubuntu since thats what the guy in the video is using, but when I tried sudo apt install clang I got a litany of errors as well. I tried googling Wmsc-not-found but didnt find much, no idea why visual studio is involved in any way, also not sure why it isn't recognizing the c library stdio, when I googled how to install c on windows it said it should be since I installed codeblocks. I am very confused and incredibly frustrated by this tutorial that did not cover how to set any of this up. Any help would be much appreciated.

running the same command from the command prompt reached via visual studio (in visual studio, tools/command line/developer command prompt) yields this error:

```
In file included from 01_01-hello.c:1:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\stdio.h:12:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt.h:10:10: fatal error: 'vcruntime.h' file not
      found
#include <vcruntime.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: clang/llvm suite doesnt come with standard libraries and headers. Just install visual studio and windows sdk and then run clang from a visual studio developer command line

Comment: or alternatively add the necessary header and library directories with your compile command.

Comment: @Destrok41 - Perhaps you shouldn't invest too much time in a frustrating tutorial. Besides, I find Ubuntu from the Windows Store (running without a virtual box) highly convenient and reliable.

Comment: where you get bash? It's really important.

Comment: @lulle I have had visual studio installed for like a year, so that doesn't really answer my question. What am I missing? In the tutorial it said to install codeblocks, and clang from the package manager if you don't have it, so what is on that guys computer that I don't have? I have visual studio, codeblocks, llvm, bash, and ubuntu installed. I tried running the clang command from the visual studio, tools/command line/developer command prompt and got a similar error.

Comment: @joshua I installed it like a year ago when in a bootcamp, I have no idea. Why does that matter?

Comment: Because different ways of having bash yield different answers.

Comment: @joshua its gitbash

Comment: It is frustrating at first, but it all works. First rule, pick your compiler and editor. You just need one of each. Visual Studio is enough on it's own. I prefer to just open the Developer Command Prompt and compile from there using the native compiler, e.g. `cl.exe /nologo /W3 /FeNameYour.exe /Tc yourCsource.c`. That will compile `yourCsource.c` into `NameYour.exe` and you can simply run `NameYour.exe` from there (no time spent with IDE's, setting up projects, etc..). To see all options, just type `cl /?`

Comment: Ubuntu in WSL is another great option. Though you will need to use a Linux editor (vim is fantastic -- it will be there for you on any Linux box you sit down to -- so it's worth learning). The command to install clang is `sudo apt-get install clang` (or just install `gcc` -- which may already be there). Either way, the options are identical, e.g. `clang -Wall -std=c11 -02 -o NameYourExe yourCsource.c` That will create `NameYourExe` which you can run as `./NameYourExe` (just remember vim has two modes `'i'` for Insert then `Esc` to return from Insert to Edit mode. `:w` to save `:q` to quit)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am running ubuntu via WSL2, running sudo apt-get install clang returns a litany of errors after I say yes, ending in several failed to fetch errors and telling me to run apt-get update which fails due to permissions? I'm so lost. NOTHING just works the way it should. also what is NameYour.exe?

Comment: ```E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin heh, turns out the issues is I was not in root. Ran sudo apt-get update and now everything works XD. A genuine thank you to everyone that commented here. Ive seen some reddit memes about stack overflow being mean, but this is my first post here and everyone was genuinely very supportive.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have Visual Studio installed and clang installed and bash from gitbash and don't know how to stack paths right.

The easiest solution is to build in clang from developer command prompt and work with git from gitbash.

The second easiest solution is to make a batch file that launches gitbash and run it from inside developer tools command prompt.

Comment: I dont know how to stack paths at all. I don't even know what that means. Im just trying to follow along a tutorial. When the bootcamp had me install visual studio and gitbash they didn't mention anything about paths. Do you have a recommendation of a good resource I can go to for that?

Comment: @Destrok41: I am routinely amazed how this gets past education. The PATH environment variable and some others is how you switch between development environments. Windows has adopted the idea of providing launchers that populate PATH; so if you need to load two or more sets of tools into the same context you run two of these, thus stacking paths.

Comment: In any case I gave you easy solutions to try.

Comment: I have added LLVM to my path but I am still getting a compile error in codeblocks telling me it cant find stdio.h, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Destrok41: The best thing to do is read what the batch file does that sets up developer command prompt.

Comment: what specifically do you mean by developer command prompt, bash? and where do I find this batch file? I have exercise files I downloaded from linkedin learning, and I hit the build button in codeblocks and get the stdio not found error.